# cmd+backspace = delete word on OSX

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, backspace

How can I make OSX backward delete one word by pressing cmd+backspace?

Currently it deletes the whole line.

Alt+Backspace works, but I want it to be cmd+backspace, like in Windows.

I tried Spark Shortcut Manager, but it didn't work.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14352/spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to most customization questions for OSX is [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). It's free, and it lets you customize keyboard shortcuts, gestures, window snapping, and more. You can even set per-app settings for shortcuts and gestures (although I haven't personally tested this).

[image: screenshot]

Set cmd+backspace to alt+backspace as in the screenshot above.

Comment: Just recently this tool became a "pay what you want" model with a minimum of 3$.  The developer behind it seems awesome, and this tool is one of the few I purchased for osx (I generally use only free tools).

Comment: The link to the tool no longer works.

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: Unfortunately this now costs a fixed amount of 8.5 USD for a 2 year license or 20 USD for a lifetime license. This value doesn't make sense just to remap a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is very popular key remapping software for key remapping. In "change Key" > "Change delete key", select "Command+Delete to Option_L+Delete". This will solve your problem. I'm attaching a screenshot also.

[image]

Comment: Just an update - [karabiner doesn't work on osx sierra](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and the suggested alternative karabiner-elements doesn't support key combinations